# How to include conditional statements in NIntegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration, conditional, singularity

I have a function `g` which is the result of another integrated function `f`. This function (`f`) has some singularities for some input values. While integrating function `f` I want to tell `NIntegrate` to take some value say `p` at singularities.

```
f[x1_, x2_, t_, ra_] = Sin[x1]*ra + 
    ra*Cos[x2]*ArcTan[x1*ra + t*x2, 
      ra*t + x1*x2];
```

This function has singularities for `ArcTan[0,0]`.

```
g[x1_, x2_, t_] := 
   With[{ff = f[x1, x2, t, ra]}, 
    NIntegrate[ff, {ra, 0, 10^(-3)}, 
     Exclusions -> ArcTan[__, __] == 0]];
```

My actual code is about 300 lines long. The above problem might help me to solve my actual problem in *Mathematica*. Kindly anyone help me.

EDITED

Adding more information

I have function "f" inside this function I have many 
`h1[ArcTan[exp1, exp2]]` , `h2[ArcTan[exp3, exp4]]`,....functions (may be more than 50 of ArcTan's are there). For some input values `exp1`, `exp2`, `exp3`, `exp4`, `exp`... goes to 0. I applied

```
f /. ArcTan[0, 0] -> p
```

at the end of the function. I was thinking When I when I substitute the input values inside f1 it will have `ArcTan[0,0]` and that gets replaced with "p".But it is not doing that. Is there a way to Replace `ArcTan[0,0]` with "p" .Then this f1 function is called for another function g where it is integrated.

Comment: I have updated the answer taking into account your "EDITED" section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read carefully the Documentation pages for [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) and [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html): your understanding of this option is wrong. It doesn't allow to specify a specific value at exclusions as you apparently think. `NIntegrate` is supposed to automatically handle singularities and all what you can do is to help it a bit by specifying them via this option. The correct usage in your case would be

```
Exclusions -> {x1*ra + t*x2 == 0 && ra*t + x1*x2 == 0}
```

Further reading:

- [Singularity Handling in `NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792) `tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies#122144792`

---

If you really do not see a better way than providing a specific value for you function at singularity points (what is a bad idea in general) you could try to turn your objective function into a `Piecewise` or a black-box function with the specific value `p` for those points:

```
NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{p, x1*ra + t*x2 == 0 && ra*t + x1*x2 == 0}}, 
  f[x1, x2, t, ra]], {ra, 0, 10^(-3)}]
```

or (if the previous doesn't work)

```
fBlackBox[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, ra_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[{{p, x1*ra + t*x2 == 0 && ra*t + x1*x2 == 0}}, f[x1, x2, t, ra]];
NIntegrate[fBlackBox[x1, x2, t, ra], {ra, 0, 10^(-3)}]
```

You can also replace `AcrTan` with a `Piecewise` function having value `p` at the singular point:

```
arcTan[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{p, x == 0 && y == 0}}, ArcTan[x, y]]
f[x1_, x2_, t_, ra_] := Sin[x1]*ra + ra*Cos[x2]*arcTan[x1*ra + t*x2, ra*t + x1*x2];
```

Of course, you can also define it via `Condition` but I'm not sure whether `NIntegrate` will handle such a definition correctly, so you probably should define `f` as a black-box function in this case as I do below:

```
arcTan[x_, y_] /; x == 0 && y == 0 := p
arcTan[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y]
fBlackBox[x1_?NumericQ, x2_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, ra_?NumericQ] := 
  Sin[x1]*ra + ra*Cos[x2]*arcTan[x1*ra + t*x2, ra*t + x1*x2];
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I tried this way it did not work though.
f[x1_, x2_, t_, ra_] = Sin[x1]*ra + 
    ra*Cos[x2]*ArcTan[x1*ra + t*x2, 
      ra*t + x1*x2] /;  ArcTan[__,__] == ArcTan[0,0] -> p; 
Is there a way to write it using Condition function

Comment: @GummalaNavneeth I'm sorry, but your code `ArcTan[, ] == ArcTan[0, 0]` just demonstrates that you don't understand even the basics of the Wolfram Language. You should learn the basics of the Wolfram Language. I recommend the [book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) by [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) as a quick start. It won't take much of your time. Please learn it before asking new questions.

Comment: @GummalaNavneeth And Yes, it is possible to write it via `Condition`, although the ways I showed in the answer should be better. But in any case, without understanding of the basics you won't be able to go further with this language.

Comment: @Alexwy Popkov Sorry for the trouble caused. I will go through that book. Thanks

Comment: @Alexwy Popkov Thanks a lot